# Why does the lxterminal not recognize the keyboard commands in raspberry pi 3?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, raspberry-pi3

I'm working with a script in a raspberry pi 3 which works with certain commands that I give through the USB keyboard in the terminal, when I execute it as

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ./script.sh
```

The code goes perfectly when i use the keyboard commands in the normal terminal, but when I leave it to start automatically through autostart in

```
sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart
```

with the command

```
@lxterminal -e ~/script.sh"
```

the keyboard commands that make the code work do not respond, there is only the terminal in doing nothing and does not recognize any action that does through the keyboard, which can be the problem?

Comment: please edit your Q with the minimal amount of code that can demonstrate the problem. Use the `{}` tool on the edit menu on selected text to get the correct `code` formatting. Please read the [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) to improve your Q. Good luck.

Comment: re-edited. Is it better now?

Comment: Not really detailed enough to be answerable in present state, no. Try to generate a [mcve] -- the shortest possible code someone can use to see the problem themselves with absolutely no additions needed. If we need to guess what your `script.sh` contains, or what kind of keyboard input is needed but not routed (something that's supposed to be read from the TTY? From stdin? From elsewhere?), that's missing context. (Don't want the whole script as it exists, but the shortest script that can be successfully tested to reproduce the same problem).

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the PATH is not set in autostart?

try following:

```
# print PATH in your terminal
echo $PATH
```

and insert this PATH at top of your script

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=...
```